# Trouble With Bulk Insert

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert some data from a txt file and I am having a lot of trouble. Whenever I try to do this I get the following error. `Cannot bulk load because the file "H:\NAPApplication.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).`

Here is the code I used for the bulk insert.

```
 BULK
    INSERT NAPApplication 
    FROM 'H:\NAPApplication.txt'
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    );
```

I used Test-Path in Powershell to double check that the file exists where I say it does. I am confused why the path specified cannot be found if it is obviously there.

EDIT: SQL Server is on a different machine than the box that the file I am looking for is on. Is there anyway to tell the computer to look into my computer instead of the server?

Comment: I think you should be using bcp instead of bulk load. That's better suited for loading something from your computer.

Comment: `'\\YourMachineName\ShareName\path\to\file.txt'` (You'll need to create the share if you don't already have one.)

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be in a location that the SQL Server can see. It cannot see your H: drive unless it is shared. Yoiu would then probably have to reference it by its UNC path. Can you not use a network share?